# Dependency Versioning Discrepancy in icroservices: Upgraded OkHttp Version in 'common' Module Not Reflected in 'service' Module's Generated JAR

Tags: java, kotlin, gradle, build.gradle, microservices

In my microservices setup, I have two modules named "common" and "service." In the "common" module's `build.gradle`, I have the following dependency configuration:

```
dependencies {
    implementation ('com.contentstack.sdk:cms:1.0.0') {
        exclude group:"org.json", module:"json"
        exclude group:"com.squareup.okhttp3", module:"okhttp"
    }
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.12.0'
}
```

I upgraded okhttp to version 4.12.0 due to security concerns with version 4.10.0. However, in the "service" module's `build.gradle`, I include the "common" module using:

```
dependencies {
    implementation project(':common')
}
```

When I build the project, the generated JAR still contains okhttp version 4.10.0. How can I fix this?

Possible solutions:

**Force Dependency Version:**
In the "service" module's `build.gradle`, explicitly specify the okhttp version to ensure that the correct version is passed to the "service" module.

```
dependencies {
    implementation project(':common')
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.12.0'
}
```

But my service module doesn't use okhttp, and it would look strange to introduce okhttp in service